# If Firefly's Mal Reynolds is a sergeant why does Zoe call him "Sir"?

Tags: character, firefly

Mal Reynolds was a sergeant at the time of the the Battle of Serenity Valley.

Why does Zoe call him "Sir" (even during the battle) when any self respecting TV Non Commissioned Officer will yell "Sir? I work for a living" in response to being called "Sir"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Malcolm is called Sir by multiple people through out the series, including Zoe and Kaylee and even Rayne (sarcasticly). He's also called Sarge, Sergeant, Cap and Captain. All titles of authority, both earned and given.

As you mentioned, this is more of a TV thing than real life. In real life, the don't call me Sir thing varies by person, and situation. Drill Sergeants on a peace time base require the cadets to call then Sir, (yes sir).

Firefly is also set a few hundred years into the future, in a neo- wild west. The terms and slang and speech has clearly changed, as noted by the inclusion of Mandarin as a lingua franca.

During the battle, the whole rebellion really, Zoe's use of formalities (Sir) is also done to keep the lower ranks inspired, reinforcing the chain of command, and the need for strict adhesion to the rules. A loose troop falls apart easier than a strict one, if current military doctrine is accurate.

Oh. And if Wash is to be believed:

> ***Don't forget to call him "sir". He likes that.***

Indicating he genuinely likes the title, ***or*** Zoe likes to screw with him cause he doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because he is the captain of the ship and is a male authority over her.  It doesn't specifically have to do with him being "Captain" as it does him being an authority. **Sir is a title of respect no matter the context.**

> **sir**
>   /sər/ 
>   noun 
>   *noun: sir; plural noun: sirs; noun: Sir; plural noun: Sirs* 
>   used as a polite or respectful way of addressing a man, especially one in a position of authority.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sir

Comment: Ok, but she calls him Sir during the flashbacks to the battle before he bought a ship. He wasn't a captain then. "Sir" is reserved for commissioned officers in the military, and many NCOs resent the implication that they didn't earn the rank but were born into it if they are called Sir. It's a no-no in the military.

Comment: Note definition, it doesn't specifically have to do with him being "Captain" as it does him being an authority. Sir is a title of respect no matter the context.

Comment: Part of the issue may be that there's a well-known TV Trope from sergeants that is "Don't call me sir, I work for a living". http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DontCallMeSir

Comment: `Sir is a title of respect no matter the context.` You sure about that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qkqki5wLZW0 http://picturequotes.org/_nw/1/22058367.jpg

Comment: Might be true (call them sir or not) in a formal military structure, but we are talking about bands of rebels, with the assumption that they don't have the formal military training or structure that the Alliance has.  Probably they're going to get some stuff technically wrong in how they throw stuff together.  Plus, if all officers are killed or you don't have anyone present, the "sir" could be way of indicating who is in charge.

Comment: Everyone seems to have completely missed the point. She calls him sir because she reports to him. He is her leader. Whether it's captain of a ship, Sargeant of a band of rebels, or coach of her little league team, etc she would call him sir as a title of respect and authority. No one makes her do it. She simply does it because of his position.

Comment: I've been called "sir" at the drive thru. That doesn't mean I've been officially knighted by the queen of england.

Comment: The Independents Army in  Firefly was analogous to the Confederate Army of the Southern States during the American Civil War. Malcolm Reynolds was in a regiment called the 57th Overlanders, indicating that they had some kind of command structure and order of battle. This may have fallen apart by the time of the Battle of Serenity Valley but it was more than them just acting as a bunch of rebels without structure.

Comment: @Hippyjim `"Sir" is reserved for commissioned officers in the military` A Brit might tell you that "Sir" is reserved for those who have been knighted by the Queen. And that's the point: different settings have different conventions. You're trying to apply the current US military convention for "Sir", but there's no reason to assume that the Firefly universe uses that _exact_ naming scheme.

Comment: Whoah, necromancy! Yeah @Flater, you're right of course. Although, being a Brit, with military experience, I was really referring to the trope that Catija mentioned - which I've encountered in painfully loud reality in real life.

It looks like there's a different feeling/usage about the word in the US, on which the culture in Firefly is heavily based.

Comment: @Hippyjim [Oops](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/15215918/shame-shame-on-the-necroposter.jpg)... But in regards to Zoe's use of "Sir" (and her usual formality in interacting Mal), it seems that Zoe simply chooses to behave militarily. Others are considerably more casual towards Mal. It does fit her character to address Mal this way. But that doesn't mean that Zoe inherently means the _military_ sir. She might simply be using the _polite_ sir, which she uses to show respect to Mal's current position (as her superior), regardless of Mal having been her superior in the army in the past.